# How to send large data in lists using AJAX GET/POST method in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, request, http-post

I want to send my table data to the server using javascript(or ajax). How can I do this?

- There will be around 2k rows.
- The data is in a list of lists.
- How to send the data in lists?

Here is what I did:

**JavaScript:**

```
          $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url:'/ccd/ajax/update-database',
            type: 'POST',
            data :{'headings':headings,'data_list':data_list,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data)
            {
              if(data.success)
              {
                console.log("success!");
              }
              else {
                console.log("error!");
              }
            }
            });
```

I'm not able to access this data in my views.py file.

I'm getting None type of data.

**Views.py**

```
def ajax_update_database(request):
    data = dict()
    data['success']=False
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method=='POST':
        headings = request.POST.get('headings')
        print(headings)
        datalist = request.POST.get('data_list')
        print(headings)
        data['success']=True
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

*Any alternative will also be appreciated.*

Comment: You can serialize an array to json and send that. So start by researching how to map your table data to array. Then how to stringify that array....then how to send it. You are asking for a complete solution but that's not how this site works. Break your issue down into smaller parts and solve each part and combine them. When you have a specific code problem with one of those parts ask questions then

Comment: You could always send it with it's full size since you serialized the table into JSON. Otherwise, you can split it into 2 or 3 part and send each part as a single request?

Comment: Ok having code changes this to a proper question. Start by inspecting the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually being sent